# Return all strings between a list of strings with regular expressions in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a list of strings like the following:

```
list = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6']
```

I would like to retrieve all the items and the indices between a pair of strings. For example, all the items between 'a2' and 'a6'.

Is there a way to do it with regular expressions?

the desire output is the following: 
(in reality I only need the indices as I can retreive all the values with the indices). 
THe reason to want regex is; I am trying to mine the output from a PDF and I am trying to mine the text and from the text extracted from the PDF I am creating a big list with all the output. From this list created from the PDF a im trying to automate these text extraction of the PDFs. As they can have variable texts and different formats I want to be able to take various formats of representing the same data.I figured regex allows to take text with slight variable format and then transform that with the desired format.

example of reference list:

```
 list = ['name', 'Mark', 'Smith', 'location', 'Florida', 'Coast', 'FL',  'date']
         location_indices = [3, 6]
desired namelst = ['name', 'Mark', 'Smith']
        location= ['location', 'Florida', 'Coast', 'FL']
```

I figured that the best way to go about this is to get the indices between Location and Date and from there I can generate the location list. Now, As my original list can vary slightly in the reference list I think regex provides me the flexibility to have slight different original list  than I can reformat.

Comment: why regex? .........

Comment: "I would like to retrieve all the items and the indices" Could you please give an example of precisely the format that you would expect given your input `list`?

Comment: `k[k.index('a2'):k.index('a6')]` , where k is the variable which contains your list

Answer (score 0):

Let's define your list:

```
>>> lst = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6']
```

(So as not to overwrite a builtin, I renamed the list to `lst`.)

Now, let's retrieve the indices and values of all items from `a2` to `a6` inclusive:

```
>>> [(i,x) for (i,x) in enumerate(lst) if lst.index('a2')<=i<=lst.index('a6')]
[(1, 'a2'), (2, 'a3'), (3, 'a4'), (4, 'a5'), (5, 'a6')]
```

Comment: Just a note that the `lst.index(...)` is an O(N) operation which is occuring once per element of `lst`, so effectively O(N^2). Would be worth storing these values once before the comprehension, though for the OP's purposes it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @CurtisLusmore Good point.  If the profiler said that this used significant time, I would move the calls to `index` outside of the list comprehension.